# Error: Number of API configs allowed on already reached 25 when deploying the application

Tags: java, google-app-engine

when I am trying the deployed the application I am getting the error:

```
Error: Number of API configs allowed on already reached
```

I know my application has more the 25 !Api endpoint classes but I have to allow all more then 25.
So please tell me how I can allow?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple

1.create one class with code:

```
@Api(name = "myendpoints", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "xxxxx.com", ownerName = "xxxxx.com", packagePath = "model"))

public class   ApiBaseClass {

    }
```

2.exnteds this class in all endpoint classes(do not write again `@Api(name="name",,,)`

This solution is worked for me.